# Slowing down 2 nested loops

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to build one of my first web apps that would visualize sorting algorithms. I'm currently working on a bubble sort algorithm but I'm having trouble slowing the bubble sort loops execution down.
I tried using setTimeout() function but apparently, it is not that easy to use it on nested loops.
The piece of code below works well but if I add setTimeout within the nested loop then it only does the first iteration of the outer while loop. It is understandable as an entire while loop is executed instantly and isn't really aware that someone has desynchronized its' body execution.

I tried putting the outer loop in a setTimeout function but I couldn't find the way to retrieve the actual time that it is supposed to be delayed by as I tried using j value to calculate it but it is only available within the for loop.

Any idea on how to slow down execution of both loops in a relevant way?

```
 bubbleSort(){
        var len = this.numberOfElements;
        var sorted = false;
        var i = 0;
        while(!sorted){
            sorted = true;
            for(let j = 0 ; j < len - i - 1; j++){ 
                setTimeout( () => {
                    if (this.valuesAndPillarsObject[j].value > this.valuesAndPillarsObject[j + 1].value) {
                        //swap graphical representation of the value
                        this.swapPillars(this.valuesAndPillarsObject[j].pillar, this.valuesAndPillarsObject[j+1].pillar);
                        // swap values
                        var temp = this.valuesAndPillarsObject[j].value;
                        this.valuesAndPillarsObject[j].value = this.valuesAndPillarsObject[j+1].value;
                        this.valuesAndPillarsObject[j + 1].value = temp;
                        sorted = false;
                    }
                }, j*40);
            }
            i++;
        }
        return this.valuesAndPillarsObject;
    }
```

Comment: `40` is 40 *milliseconds*.  First step in trying to slow it down, increase that timeout value to be larger.

Comment: If you tell 24 people "please come back in one hour", do you think it will be 24 hours until the last person comes back?  You may be surprised to see that all 24 people return after just one hour.  Calling setTimeout in a loop is the same deal.

Comment: This question is conflating the concept of _slowing down_ with the concept of _asynchronous programming_.  This is really a question about **async**.  I kinda wish the words "slow down" didn't even occur in the question.  As even 20k+ rep @Taplar took the bait on that one.

Comment: @Wyck You are ignoring the point that their set timeouts timeout is not a set amount of time.  It is derived with `j * 40`.  So while the for loop *will* create all (lets say 24) timeouts, if instead of `40` the user put `5000`, then the first timeout would execute after 5 seconds.  The second one after 10 seconds, and so on and so forth.  That may not be the entirety of their issue, but taking into account the desire to delay in a progressive nature the execution of the timeouts, this is one approach.  An argument can be made it is not a good approach, but it is an approach.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to just schedule a bunch of timeouts in a loop.  They'll all finish after just one delay.  You want to have each timeout start the next one.  To keep using a loop to control the flow, you'll need to make use of **async** and **await**.

#### Wrong way

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  setTimeout(() => { console.log(`step ${i}`) }, 1000);
}
console.log('finished');
```

#### Right way

```js
const delay = time_ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time_ms));

const main = async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    await delay(1000);
    console.log(`step ${i}`);
  }
}

main().then(() => console.log('finished'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop will finish before the first setTimeout callback is called !
even if the timeout is 1ms or 0ms.
read some about the [EventLoop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) to understand how things works in JavaScript.

**UPDATE:** the simplest solution is using delay inside the for loop.
just like how *Wyck* did.
but here i will keep the other solutions

You can use function and call it again to demonstrate a loop instead of normal for loop.

```js
// change the code as your needs
const sleep = (t) =>  ({ then: (r) => setTimeout(r, t) })
const len =10

 // change slowFor for your needs
const slowFor= async (i,j)=>{
    // do what you want here
    await sleep(5000)
    if(j == len) return ;
    console.log("after sleeping call next loop");
    
    slowFor(i,j+1)

}


slowFor(0,0)
```

be aware of maximum call stack when running on big arrays.

or you can convert the bubbleSort function to a generator function so you will be able to stop it whenever and as much time you want.

change the code to fit your need

```js
function* bubble() {    
    
    for(let i = 1 ; i<10 ; i++ ){
        for(let j=0 ; j<i ; j++, yield){
            console.log("hellow from for");
        }
    }

}

const genBubble = bubble()

genBubble.next()
setInterval(() => {
    
    genBubble.next()

}, 5000);
```